# Deletion of list elements by rule

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string list that consists of elements that have 3 sub-elements:

```
lis = {{"ac", "b", "ca"}, {"ab", "cde", "f,h"}, {"cd", "gh", "kl,"}};
```

I would like to delete each list member whose third element lacks a comma, which gives:

```
res = {{"ab", "cde", "f,h"}, {"cd", "gh", "kl,"}}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select[lis,StringContainsQ[","]@*Last]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Cases[lis, {__, _?(StringContainsQ[","])}]
```

alternatively

```
Replace[lis, x_ /; StringFreeQ[Last[x], ","] -> Nothing, {1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Selecting sublist elements where the last element has a comma:

```
Pick[lis, StringContainsQ[Last /@ lis, ","]]
```

Selecting sublist elements where the last element lacks a comma:

```
Pick[lis, StringFreeQ[Last /@ lis, ","]]
```